# SQL Primary key autoincrement vs timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, timestamp, primary-key

**Premesis:**

I know that the best way to use a primary key is to set the field as integer (autoincrement or not) due to indexes, but I'm in a particular situation...

I have a program that works offline (on both pc and tablet) using sqlite as a database.
The user can sync the datas between the program and the central server (like a cloud).
When the user sync the datas, all the local update field are updated on server and viceversa.

Using a primary key autoincrement in this situation is a bad solution because if two users add a field in a table (on two different device) I'll have the primary key duplicated..

Then I added another field that contains the ID of the user so I have an index formed by:
`USER_ID` and `FIELD_ID` this way the situation change but still there can be problems...

1) I can't have the FIELD_ID as AUTO_INCREMENT
2) The problem described above still remains, 
    if the User Paul has two device with the same database version (synced at the same time), and in the device 1 he does an insert on table_AAA and he does another insert on table_AAA but from device 2, I will have a duplicate index (USER_ID / FIELD_ID)

So I converted the FIELD_ID as a varchar(17) composed by YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmm, this way is pretty impossible that an user make two operation at the same millisecond..

***The Question:***

Is there  a better way to set the primary key in my situation???

Comment: just a thought, you say it's "pretty impossible" that two updates are made at the same millisecond but what if the system time is altered?

Comment: Why doesn't a composite primary key work for you? (user_id, device_id, field_id)?  This not only gives uniqueness, but also specifically locates where the data was generated.  Whatever you do, feel free to use the timestamp for any reason ***except*** as a unique identifier.  You *will* eventually get collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Create a second, unique field, a guid.  You get your fast indexing for regular usage, and uniqness for merging.

Comment: Technically you can create two GUIDs that match.  I don't know how many universe lifetimes that would take though ;)  Timestamps can't be assumed to be unique at all, but GUIDs *really* can be assumed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) as the primary key, to add more clarity you can add a device_id field to distinguish rows, though `UUID` should suffice.

By the way, `UUID`s results ascend, that is table data fragmentation should not bother you much.

Comment: timestamp outperforms UUID in performance.

Answer (score 0):

`Long` outperforms `UUID` in almost every aspect. I'd suggest you use `Long` type pk using timestamp values. So, when a device wants to create an object (either offline or online), it assigns its current timestamp (in milliseconds or even nano) to the pk value of the new object.